# PHP не видит сессию

Tags: apache, php, yii, сессия

Привет всем! У меня 2 инстанса апача висятна разных портах - 80, и 84. на 80 порту обрабатываются запросы, отправленные на site.com, на 84 порту обрабатываются запросы, поступающие на site.com/myurl.Делается это за счет использования проксирования (директива ProxyPass в конфигах апача.). Т.е., когда приходит запрос на site.com/myurl, он перенаправляется на ext.site.com/myurl

Проблема в том, что когда запрос, проксируемый с site.com/myurl перенаправляется на ext.site.com/myurl, кука сохраняется, но когда в скрипте, вызываемом по адресу ext.site.com/myurl делаю

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

в ответ мне выводится пустой массив. В чем может быть дело? php 5.3, apache2, debian 6

Comment: Вопрос, а зачем при использовании Yii ты используешь **session_start();** ???

У фреймворка же есть механизм работы с авторизацией.

Comment: Нужно было сделать сквозную авторизацию, а т.к. наш Yii-шник вату катал, а Я с этим фреймворком был плохо знаком, но при этом нужно было сделать сквозную авторизацию очень срочно, зафигачил в контроллер в методе Init получение сессии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто нужно было перезагрузить апач. Там у парней какой-то сбой был на серверном железе. После этого все стало ок.

Answer (score 2):

Сессия не передаётся на поддомен, перед переходом ставьте куку с ID сессии на весь *.site.com

Comment: Перед переходом с site.com на ext.site.com ?

Comment: @nolka, да

Comment: Спасибо, попробуем)

Answer (score 1):

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site.com');
session_start();
```

Comment: Не проканало)